# Setting Gii permissions in yii2

Tags: linux, yii2

i am working on a project 'demo' in a system with ip address 'xxx.xxx.x.x'  from another system with a different ip address. when i try to use `gii` i get a permission error. how can i set permission for using `gii` in a separate system ?
i tried like this in main-local.php

```
 if ( !YII_ENV_TEST )
    {
        // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
        $config[ 'bootstrap' ][ ]       = 'debug';
        $config[ 'modules' ][ 'debug' ] = 'yii\debug\Module';

        $config[ 'bootstrap' ][ ]     = 'gii';
        $config[ 'modules' ][ 'gii' ]['allowedIPs'] = ['*'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have ip like 127.0.0.1 then, try

```
$config['modules']['gii'] = [
    'class'=>'yii\gii\Module',
    'allowedIPs'=>['127.0.0.*'],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not a good pratice accessing gii in remote but anyway 
try specific allowed ip in `backend/config/main.php`

```
'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1',  'xxx.xxx.x.x'],
```